# Обман screen lock

Tags: python

На компьютерах стоит обязательный screen lock, а у меня на них тяжелые просчеты, так вот вывести их потом из режима заставки и залогиниться довольно проблематично, т.к. загруженность 100%. В обход системы попробовал с помощью питона двигать мышкой раз в 100 секунд, мышка то двигается, но вот скрин локк все равно срабатывает.

Есть ли возможность это обойти и обмануть локк?

```
import time
import ctypes

class POINT(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("x", ctypes.c_ulong), ("y", ctypes.c_ulong)]

def click():
    def queryMousePosition_X():
        pt = POINT()
        ctypes.windll.user32.GetCursorPos(ctypes.byref(pt))
        return pt.x

    def queryMousePosition_Y():
        pt = POINT()
        ctypes.windll.user32.GetCursorPos(ctypes.byref(pt))
        return pt.y

    x = (queryMousePosition_X()- 50)
    y = (queryMousePosition_Y() - 50)
    ctypes.windll.user32.SetCursorPos(x, y)

def check_time():
    while True:
        click()
        time.sleep(100)

check_time()
```

Comment: Вы спрашиваете как хранитель экрана на вашей версии Windows выключить?

Comment: его нельзя выключить, в том и дело, я пытаюсь его обмануть

Comment: я не знал что нельзя хранитель экрана на Windows выключить. А как вы кино смотрите тогда?

Comment: Это я к тому, что я не верю, что на одной из основных систем нельзя видео смотреть не крутя мышкой.

Comment: есть разные системы защиты, порвете и не такое бывает, это не встроенные функционал, суть в том что надо как то винде сказать что двигает мышкой не скрипт питона, а человек :)

Comment: Тогда спрашивать про конкретную систему надо—обычно в таких вещах гонка вооружений. В [связанном вопросе](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1181464/4279) дополнительно к вашему коду ещё события генерируются `mouse_event()`.

Answer (score 1):

Поставьте расчетным процессам пониженный приоритет - тогда они не будут мешать нормальной работе системных процессов.

Вот тут приведен способ понизить приоритет текущему процессу на Питоне:

[Change process priority in Python, cross-platform](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1023269/4340086)

Comment: Объясните, пожалуйста, как понижение приоритета процесса не даст системе заблокировать рабочую станцию (win + L) при неактивности пользователя?

Comment: @gil9red проблема автора не в самой блокировке - а в том, что запущенный процесс не дает ее разблокировать обратно. Процесс с пониженным приоритетом не будет мешать системным процессам - а потому необходимости обходить блокировку больше нет.

Comment: Это так, но вопрос все-же был в другом "Есть ли возможность это обойти и обмануть локк? " :)

Comment: понизить приоритет это не проблема, ситуация такая что все компьютеры(клиенты) которые впадают в состояние простоя рано или поздно отваливаются от сервера, проблема все еще не решена, но как мне подсказывали другие специалисты, нужен более низкоуровневый язык, C например

Comment: так как в случае с Python не будет возможности имитировать команду с контроллера.

Comment: @Oleksii вот эту проблему и надо решать!

Comment: @Oleksii опишите ее в отдельном вопросе или исправьте этот. Нет никаких причин чтобы клиент отваливался от сервера сам собой. Screen Lock придуман не просто так, и "обманывать" его когда безопасники требуют прямо противоположного - неправильно.